# Accept only single dot while getting files?

Tags: php, html

When i try to upload a image using php, it accepts files ending with .php.jpg for example: `acp_1.php.jpg` How to stop a user from adding this kind of files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: What's the problem with filenames containing two dots? [This sounds like an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why don't you then just check if there's more than one dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strpos($string, '.php')`.
TThen just do a condition if(strpos(***)), and you can then prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Using this regex:

^[^\.\s]+\.[^\.\s]+$

Ensures a unique point wrapped with non-space characters around, doing the job you asked.